# How to access value of session saved from javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I my application i am saving minutes value in session from javascript in a function.
My code is

```
 function redo() {
      .
      .
      .

    '<%Session["mins"] = "' + mins + '";%>';                        
    alert('session min value after is ' + '<%=Session["mins"]%>');

}
```

Minute value in session is shown in alert but when i access it in code behind

session contains "' + mins + '".
My code is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var aa = Convert.ToInt32(Session["mins"]);
        }
```

Minutes value is not available in code behind.

How to get session value in code behind ?

Answer (score 2):

Session is a serverside concept. The only way(*) for the client to know it is to ask the server (through inclusion in the originally rendered page, or through AJAX).

---

*) In some realisations of the session concept, the session itself is stored in the cookie, and the client could access and decode it there. This is not reliable, nor recommended, and not available in all frameworks.

Comment: Why would you say that a cookie is not reliable?

Comment: @ Amadan could you provide me some code to perform inclusion in the originally rendered page

Comment: @jfriend00: I did not say that cookies are unreliable, I said reading cookies to get at session values is. Because a cookie-based session store could be switched at any time to a database-backed session store or file-backed session store, or the format of the cookie could be changed... basically, you should read the session only using the API that created it, anything else is a hack, and therefore unreliable. Actually, I don't even think ASP supports a cookie-based session store, so the whole point is moot for the OP.

Comment: OK fine.  But there are zillions of web-sites all over the world that put a session in a cookie and read that session from the cookie and your wording made it sound like that concept is unreliable which it is not.  It can certainly be done reliably.  Obviously if the OP wants to use the tools built into ASP for sessions, then they can stick to the session access offered in the framework.

Comment: @jfriend00: The zillions are in the vast majority doing it on the server, through the serverside API (`$_SESSION[]`, `request.session`...) and almost never through actually reading the cookie manually; thus, if they switched the backing store, the code would not change a bit. Zillions of web-sites most certainly don't access their cookie-stored sessions on the clientside, which was what the question is about.

Answer (score -1):

Assign the value to a hidden control and access that in JS code